# SUDS, Python: how do you convert a return object to python data-type

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, suds

In SUDS when i call a method on the server and receive it's response, i access the return values/attributes *using . notation (attribute access)*. Is there a way for me to have the response stored in a python object - after all the WSDL/SUDS has an idea of the structure of the server-data-type.

eg:
SOAP Type: ClientInfo

```
(reply){
   Transaction = 
      (Transaction){
         Reference1 = "1"
         Reference2 = "2"
         Reference3 = "3"
         Reference4 = "4"
         Reference5 = "5"
      }
   Notifications = ""
   HasErrors = False
   Countries = 
      (ArrayOfCountry){
         Country[] = 
            (Country){
               Code = "AD"
               Name = "Andorra"
               IsoCode = "020"
               StateRequired = False
               PostCodeRequired = False
               PostCodeRegex = None
               InternationalCallingNumber = "376"
            },
```

Can i dump this into a python data-type/object by using the wsdl info?

Answer (score 0):

The suds object *is* a python object, you're just looking at the print representation. Suds has many hooks where you can digest its results.

https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation

Comment: yes, all objects within python are python-objects - what I mean is, in python, when you do: print(cls.client.factory.create("Address")) you will get <class 'suds.sudsobject.Address'> which is actually a WSDL data-type "address' that has been replicated in Python as a class called 'Address' which is built up of native python-data-types (dict, list). You access this python class using the . (attribute notation). Is it possible to strip the class layer and get a an object (dict, list, tuple) that mirrors the layout of 'Address'

Comment: link is dead :(

Comment: same here link is down, anywhere else to look up ?